# May I travel in Schengen zone with an expired EU passport?

Tags: schengen, passports

The passport has expired 2 years ago. I want to travel by plane on a direct flight from Lisbon to Austria. I might not be able to get a new passport from my embassy on time (I'm a resident in Portugal). The only other document I have is an Austrian divers license.

Comment: It's can help you - http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm

Comment: which airline operates the flight?

Comment: @GuidoPreite: it is with TAP, direct flight to Vienna

Comment: In that case it doesn't matter since you're taking a domestic and not an international flight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that both Portugal and Austria are part of the EU the flight you're taking is actually "domestic" rather then international, so there is no requirement to have a valid passport since you're not crossing any borders either outbound or inbound.

To be more specific according to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=AT&AR=PT&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=AT&EM=PT&TR=00&VT=00&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) you can enter Austria on an expired passport if it's expired within the last 5 years.  With the exemption of:

> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Holders of a National ID Card issued to nationals of
>   Austria.

Comment: Incidentally, my hunch was confirmed by your link, the expired passport is useful, the driver's license not so much and this has nothing to do with the flight being domestic or not crossing any borders (which is not true, Austria and Portugal are still different countries). You should really correct your answer because as it stands, it's still wrong and misleading.

Comment: Not all Schengen countries accept their own passports when expired. A Dutch passport used to be for 5 years and at 5 years and one day it was a useless piece of paper.